# Persisting home and user data through full rebuild

Tags: server, mount, ssh

I have a remote server with several users who connect via SSH. I need to periodically replace the server -- effectively rebuilding from scratch -- but want to retain the user home directories. I currently have the `/home` directory mounted on a partition on a separate disk that I detach before the server is destroyed and that I reattach after the new server is up, but before any of the users connect.

However, when a user connects to the newly built server, they get console output that says:

```
Creating directory '/home/<username>'.
```

and their home directory is empty. How can I configure the server to re-use the existing directories?

Version: Ubuntu, 22.04 LTS, amd64 jammy image built on 2023-10-25

*Edits: adding information and clarifying*

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by _server rebuild_. You have given no information on how the users are created after the "rebuild". Also, it is not clear whether the `/home` is remounted (after the server "rebuild" and) before users are logged in. Please, [edit] your question and add this information, together with the Ubuntu version.

Comment: Thanks for the note - will do!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And provide us more detail.